# CMake custom command for bison target

Tags: c, cmake, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I'm trying to convert an old Autotools project to CMake. In one of the Makefiles, there are some rules that use lex and yacc.
I found that CMake has `bison_target` and `flex_target`. However in the Makefile there's a rule with `sed` that edit the generated file. 
Here is the `Makefile.am`:

```
docdir = @SIS_DOCDIR@
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DSIS -I../include
AM_YFLAGS = -d

BUILT_SOURCES = readlib.c readlib.h readliblex.c
CLEANFILES = $(BUILT_SOURCES)

noinst_LIBRARIES = libgenlib.a
libgenlib_a_SOURCES = aoi.c com_genlib.c comb.c comb.h count.c genlib.c \
    genlib.h genlib_int.h io.c nand.c permute.c sptree.c sptree.h \
    readlib.y readliblex.l
dist_doc_DATA = genlib.doc

readlib.h: readlib.c
readlib.c readlib.h: readlib.y
    $(YACC) $(YFLAGS) $(AM_YFLAGS) $<
    sed 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' y.tab.c > readlib.c
    sed 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' y.tab.h > readlib.h
    $(RM) y.tab.c y.tab.h
readliblex.c: readliblex.l readlib.h
    $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) $(AM_LFLAGS) $<
    sed 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' lex.yy.c > readliblex.c
    $(RM) lex.yy.c
```

And this is how I translated it:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -DSIS)
add_library(genlib STATIC
        aoi.c
        com_genlib.c
        comb.c
        count.c
        genlib.c
        io.c
        nand.c
        permute.c
        sptree.c

        readlib.y
        readliblex.l
        )
find_package(BISON)
find_package(FLEX)
bison_target(readlib readlib.y -d)
add_custom_command(TARGET readlib POST_BUILD
        COMMAND sed 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' y.tab.c > readlib.c
        COMMAND sed 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' y.tab.h > readlib.h
        COMMAND rm -f y.tab.c y.tab.h
        )
flex_target(readliblex readliblex.l lex.yy.c)
add_custom_command(TARGET readliblex POST_BUILD
        COMMAND sed 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' lex.yy.c > readliblex.c
        COMMAND rm -f lex.yy.c
        )
```

The problem is that CMake doesn't see `readlib` and `readliblex` as targets:

```
CMake Error at sis/genlib/CMakeLists.txt:28 (add_custom_command):
  No TARGET 'readlib' has been created in this directory.


CMake Error at sis/genlib/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_custom_command):
  No TARGET 'readliblex' has been created in this directory.
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `bison_target` didn't create a target, I ended up using a different solution:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -DSIS)

find_package(BISON REQUIRED)
find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)

set(BISON_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readlib.c)
if (BISON_FOUND)
    add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT ${BISON_OUTPUT}
            COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}
            --output=${BISON_OUTPUT}
            -d
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readlib.y
            COMMENT "Generating readlib.c"
    )
endif ()

set(FLEX_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readliblex.c)
if (FLEX_FOUND)
    add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT ${FLEX_OUTPUT}
            COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}
            --outfile=${FLEX_OUTPUT}
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readliblex.l
            COMMENT "Generating readliblex.c"
    )
endif ()

add_library(genlib STATIC
        aoi.c
        com_genlib.c
        comb.c
        count.c
        genlib.c
        io.c
        nand.c
        permute.c
        sptree.c
        ${BISON_OUTPUT}
        ${FLEX_OUTPUT}
        )
add_custom_command(TARGET genlib POST_BUILD
        COMMAND sed -i 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readlib.c
        COMMAND sed -i 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readlib.h
        COMMAND sed -i 's/yy/GENLIB_yy/g' ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sis/genlib/readliblex.c
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite of its name, `bison_target` doesn't create a CMake *target*. It is just `add_custom_command()` invocation which *OUTPUT* files, listed in `BISON_<name>_OUTPUT` variable.

Comment: That's why it didn't work. I ended up using another solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the generated source code to replace the `'yy'` prefix, it is better to tell bison to use a prefix when generating code:

For bison before 2.6:

```
bison --name_prefix=GENLIB_yy
```

For bison after 2.6:

```
bison -Dapi.prefix=GENLIB_yy
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option to use the `add_custom_target()` and additional CMake script.

```
add_library(genlib STATIC
  aoi.c
  com_genlib.c
  comb.c
  count.c
  genlib.c
  io.c
  nand.c
  permute.c
  sptree.c
  ${BISON_readlib_OUTPUTS}
)

find_package(BISON)

bison_target(readlib readlib.y COMPILE_FLAGS -d)

add_custom_target(
  patchReadlibFiles
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/Foo/patch_readlib_file.cmake"
  DEPENDS ${BISON_readlib_OUTPUTS}
)

add_dependencies(genlib patchReadlibFiles)
```

Contents of patch_readlib_file.cmake script:

```
message(STATUS "Patching readlib.c")
file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/readlib.c" file_contents)
string(REPLACE "yy" "GENLIB_yy" file_contents "${file_contents}")
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/readlib.c" "${file_contents}")

message(STATUS "Patching readlib.h")
file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/readlib.h" file_contents)
string(REPLACE "yy" "GENLIB_yy" file_contents "${file_contents}")
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/readlib.h" "${file_contents}")
```

This way the patchReadlibFiles target depends on bison execution and it will be run before building the genlib target.